# OpenGL ES draw white, black, and black, clear?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

Is there a way, in OpenGL ES 1.0, to draw the white parts of a texture, black, and the black parts, clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this requires programmable pipeline. OpenGL ES 2.0 can do it